# ASP.NET OAuth 2.0 Google Local Debugging

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth

I have added OAuth 2.0 authentication to my VS2013/ASP.NET 4.5 website, I have copied all the OAuth code from an empty wizard generated app, I have set everything on Google developer account, but my web app does not login and also there are no errors on google, it just redirects back without being logged.

When I start the website in debug mode it requests for google credentials and after I click accept it redirects back without being logged in, but I don't know where to debug in the OAuth code to see the problem?